# Create MYSQL Trigger To Update Column based on calculation of another column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this table

```
id     price     qty     points
```

How can I create a trigger so that whenever I update the column price, the column points will be updated based on the calculation of price DIV 10 DIV qty?

I have tried but it does not work and it doesn't update the column points.

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists cart_update_rewards$$
create trigger cart_update_rewards
after update on cart
for each row 
begin
SELECT `price` DIV 10 DIV `quantity` as points FROM `cart`;
end$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved it with help from @GordonLinoff.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON cart FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- trigger code
set new.`reward_points` = new.cart_price DIV 1;
END; // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the value to a column in `cart`, use a "before update" trigger and assign the value in `new`:

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists cart_update_rewards$$
create trigger cart_update_rewards
before update on cart
for each row 
begin
    set new.points = new.price DIV 10 DIV new.quantity ;
end$$
```

Comment: I am trying to update the column after I update the field cart_price. I have tried using "after update" but it gives the error "#1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger ". I tried removing the "new", it prompted "#1193 - Unknown system variable 'reward_points' "?

Comment: @phpSiao . . . You cannot update a field in the same table *after* the update is completed, using a trigger.  You want a before update trigger, if the change is on the same table.

Comment: Yup, so I've noticed. Thanks.